# bind array to DataGridViewComboBoxCell c#

Tags: c#, datagridviewcomboboxcell

```
 private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable Dt = DB.SelectItemDetails(Convert.ToString(txtItemList.Text));

        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
        row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = Dt.Rows[0]["ItemName"] });
        row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = Dt.Rows[0]["ItemPrice"] });
        int num = Convert.ToInt16(Dt.Rows[0]["Qty"]);
        int[] numArry = new int[num];
        for (int i =1 ; i == num; i++)
        {
            numArry[i] = i;
        }

        row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewComboBoxCell { Value =  }
        dgvBill.Rows.Add(row);



    }
```

need to add numArry to DataGridViewComboBoxCell tried so many ways but still couldn't figure it

Comment: Y9u should use datasource property of DataGridViewComboBoxCell. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i read that but couldn't find how to figure this

Comment: You need to Do `row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewComboBoxCell { DataSource = numArry });`

Comment: it worked. thank you